# Why the speed of light is represented by $c$?

Tags: speed-of-light, terminology, notation

In almost every textbook, I've found that the speed of light is $c \approx 3 \times 10^8\: \mathrm{m/s}$. I wonder why it's just $c$ ?

Comment: You may check [this link](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/c.html)

Comment: Hi, here is a link with a very nice and exhaustive answer to this question: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/c.html

Comment: @Zet: you were 46 seocnd faster ;)

Comment: I always thought it stood for "cpeed of light" : )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [naming conventions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/are-physics-related-notation-and-terminology-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 11):

It's *c* for *constant* or *celeritas*, which means speed in Latin. Everyone uses it because it's convention. You could use $\xi$ or $\zeta$ or $\gamma$ or any other symbol you wanted, but then you'd have to explain what it meant, and people would have to go through the trouble to remember this every time they read your papers. Better to go with convention and save everyone the headache